# How to parse specific lines of data in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with lines of data. Each line ends with "`# Source [number]`". There could be multiple sources such as "`# Source 1,3`".

Example of the text:

```
This is line one   # Source 3
This is line two   # Source 2
This is line three # Source 4,5
This is line four  # Source 5
This is line five  # Source 2
```

**Question:**
How can I parse only the lines with sources interested. I want to get the lines that are in sources 4 and above. The result should be a list or dict as follows:

```
This is line three
This is line four
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide inputs and expected results. This might be a case of regex and to help you out, we need to know what you expected exactly. For example if you are looking for `# Source 5`, is `# Source 4,5` included or it must match exactly the interested sources.

Comment: Try using [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) when you read the file line by line with `#` as the separator.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly overengineered but works exactly the way you want

```py
import re

subject = """This is line one   # Source 3
This is line two   # Source 2
This is line three # Source 4,5
This is line four  # Source 5
This is line five  # Source 2
"""

matches = re.findall(r"[Source\s][\d(,)]{1,}", subject)
matches = list(map(lambda x: int(x) if not "," in x else list(map(int, x.split(","))), matches))
matches = list(map(lambda y: y if isinstance(y, int) else max(y), matches))

subject_lines = subject.splitlines()
subject_lines = list(map(lambda z: z[0], list(map(lambda q: q.split("#"), subject_lines))))

for index, each_source_value in enumerate(matches):
    if each_source_value >= 4:
        print(subject_lines[index])
```

Output :

```
This is line three 
This is line four
```

And works with other subject strings with similar conditions as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code will select lines based on the value given from input:

```
number = input("Get lines for source higher or equal than: ")

result = []

with open("D:/data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        phrase, comment = line.split("#")

        for item in comment.replace(",", " ").split():
            try:
                if int(item) >= int(number):
                    result.append(phrase.strip())
                    break
            except ValueError:
                pass

print(result)
```

For input value `4` this will output:

```
['This is line three', 'This is line four']
```